# How to move elements in std::vector by 1?

Tags: c++

I have dynamic array with user-defined type:

```
std::vector<Pipe> pipes = {Pipe(640),Pipe(480),Pipe(320),Pipe(160)};
```

then I want to remove last element of an array, move all elements by 1 to the right and insert another `Pipe()` at index of 0. For now I've got:

```
pipes.pop_back();
pipes.insert(pipes.begin(),Pipe(inf * 160);
inf++;
```

Note this is in a loop and initial value of inf is 5. I print values from Pipe class - constructor parameter is stored in a variable - at the end and they should be: 800, 640, 480, 320.

Instead they are: 800, 480 , 320 , 160.
And after another iteration : 960, 640 , 320, 160.

That's because I'm just replacing the pipes[0] with another value before "moving" the array.
So my question is how do I do that?

Also sorry for bad explanation I'm still learning.

Comment: are you stuck with vectors or can you change the container?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Comment: I can change the container.

Comment: I tried 'pipes.pop_back();
pipes.push_front(Pipe(inf * 160.f));' but the result remained the same.

Comment: Using a [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) this would just be `push_front()` followed by `pop_back()`.

Comment: I fixed it it turned out in push_front I've should've used Pipe(640) instead of Pipe(inf * 160) since Pipes are moving. How stupid of me!

Comment: Use deque. If you need to loop over the vector many times and want to avoid cache misses, you could try a circular vector, i.e.: replace your last element with the new one and set the first index equal to size()-1.
Then you iterate over the indexes with index%size(). The next element you would replace is then at index 0, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `std::rotate` to move everything to the right by 1 element. Then assign a new `Pipe` to the `0` element.

```
#include <algorithm>

// Move all elements to the right by 1
std::rotate(pipes.begin(), std::next(pipes.begin()), pipes.end());

// Create a new Pipe at the beginning
pipes[0] = Pipe(inf * 160);
```

Comment: This rotates to the left, not to the right. Switch `begin()` and `end()` with `rbegin()` and `rend()` to easily get a right-rotation.

Comment: Why should we need to involve `std::rotate` here?
`std::vector::insert` to the same operation.
1) `pipes.pop_back();` 2) `pipes.insert(std::next(pipes.begin(), ...)`. Easy

Comment: @BiagioFesta Because you cannot insert a range from a container into itself, see: [*"Neither i nor j are iterators into a."*](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.sequence.requirements)